# Facebook Opengraph Read Action

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Right I asked a similar question but didn't word it coherently so here goes.

I'm trying to use Facebook opengraph to instigate a read action for articles on my site using php code.

I want to use the opengraph to post a read action for the current url. I've tried this so far but with no joy

```
    <?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>





<?php

$facebook->api('https://graph.facebook.com/me/:read?  
                article='echo curPageURL();'','POST')


?>
```

As many clever cloggs have pointed out I am a novice and this is my best attempt so please be patient

Answer (score 0):

The API calls looks to be incorrect. If you are using the build-in 'read' action, try something like:

```
$facebook->api('/me/news.reads?article=' . curPageURL(),'POST');
```

You don't need to use the full graph URL in the API call. Make sure you have permission to publish actions for the user too or the API call will fail. If the call is successful, you will get the ID of the published action back.